Algunos de los paquetes y comandos por la terminal dejan de funcionar al reiniciarla (Linux)
Hoy intenté instalar nix (el manejador de paquetes) y Yazi (herramienta para CLI), al principio funcionaron bien, pero al iniciar una terminal nueva ya no me reconcía los comandos. Mi sistema operativo es Nobara (una distribución de linux basada en Fedora)
Lo más extraño es que unas horas antes instalé fzf y bat (otras 2 herramientas de CLI) y siguen funcionando.
Mi teoría es que este error tiene que ver con cómo los instalé:
fzf =  sudo dnf install fzf
bat =  sudo dnf install bat
nix =  curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install | sh
yazi = nix-env -iA nixpkgs.yazi
(tanto fzf como bat los instalé con el instalador de paquetes de mi distro, mientras que nix lo descargué desde la página web con curl y yazi utilizando nix).
Gracias.

Ese tipo de cambios normalmente te pide hacer logout/login, para que todos tus terminales/sesiones se inicien con el mismo ambiente. Los cambios que hacen en una terminal no se reflejan en los otros (el PATH, por ejemplo).

Parece como si la shell no  estubiera cargando el profile para establece el entorno para nix.  En la terminal nueva ejecuta source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh y prueba a ver si puedes usar nix.

Si es esto, puedes agregarlo a tu .bashrc. De cualquier forma, en fedora te recomiendo usar Determinate Systems nix installer para instalar Nix, más que nada para no tener que configurar todo manualmente para que funcione bien junto a SELinux.

PERFECTO!, el comando de source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh funcionó, muchas gracias, tambien resolvió el bug de yazi. Probaré Determinate Systems nix installer de todos modos. Gracias FJSevilla.

si querés ponelo como respuesta así te lo marco como correcto y cierro la pregunta.
PD: si podés votar para arriba mi pregunta me hacés un favor inmenzo, que quiero llegar a los 15 puntos en stack overflow

@Lorenzo he creado una respuesta con básicamente mis comentarios algo mejor redactados... Saludos.

El problema está en que Nix no se se está cargando en el nuevo en entorno.
Seguramente el instalador modificó ~/.bash_profile para cargar el perfil de usuario de nix en el entorno, pero .bash_profile no se carga cuando inicias la terminal desde el escritorio.
Dado que es una instalación de usuario, puedes activar el entorno ejecutando en cada nueva shell:
$ source ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh

o puedes modificar tu .bashrc agregando:
~/.bashrc
# Nix
if [ -e $HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh ]; then
    source $HOME/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh;
fi

para que ésto tenga lugar automáticamentea al inciar cada nueva shell.
En las instalaciones multiusuario en principio ésto debería estar resulto ya que se encarga de ello /etc/profile.d/nix.sh.

Mencionar que actualmente instalar nix mediante el instalador oficial tradicional en Fedora es problemático ya que SELinux no es oficialmente soportado y requiere generalmente de algunos retoques manuales para hacerlo compatible con el mismo. Ésto puede cambiar en un futuro si se resuelven las issues actualmente abiertas y se da soporte oficial a sistemas con SELinux habilitado y fedora concretamente.
Una alternativa mucho más sencilla a día de hoy es usar en su lugar el instalador de Determinate Systems.

sos un crack jaja, te daría un voto para arriba pero aún no puedo xd
